# Two same script PHP on one page

Tags: php

I have problem with input 2 same php script on one page.

When i put first script everything is alright

```
<div id="jcart">
    <?php $jcart->display_cart();?>
</div>
```

When I put this same code second time, my all site is crashed and I can't move on to another subpages.
I have read that I can use an iframe to get it work, so I have put this code.

```
<div id="jcart">
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['called'])) {
        echo '<iframe src="test.php?called=y"></iframe>';
    }
?> 
</div>
```

But i have an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function display_cart() on a non-object
>   in /home/movsitev/domains/aba.vxm.pl/public_html/test.php on line 2

My test.php look like this

```
<?php 
    $jcart->display_cart();
?>
```

Comment: probably, in your iframe you are not on the same session

Comment: I don't understand You, could be more specify?

Comment: "Call to a member function display_cart() on a non-object " means on that page you probably haven't included the function display_cart

Comment: @unixmiah no. "Call to a member function display_cart() on a non-object " means that $jcart is not an object. So he is probably null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the same id on the same page.  If you want to use multiple elements with the same attribute name, change `id="jchart"` to `class="jchart"`.  also do the same in your CSS.  Also, make sure you're defining the display_chart function on this page, not on an external one.